# Youtube iFrame API wont control player

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I am making a site where I need external controls for an embedded Youtube video.
The problem is that the play button doesn't work when it's inside the `onPlayerReady` function.
This it the markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api"></script>
<div>
   <iframe id="player" width="560" height="315"  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/08HqRzhqXU0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="play_btn">PLAY</div>
```

And this is my script:

```
var player;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
            events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            }
        });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    var playButton = document.getElementById("play_btn");
    playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
        player.playVideo();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the [enablejsapi](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#enablejsapi) parameter on the iframe source.